# Code to plot a line for Tradestation Easylanguge

Tags: plot, line, draw, tradestation, easylanguage

I'm a beginner in coding and would appreciate some assistance. I'm interested in creating an EasyLanguage script that I can adjust manually each time. What I'd like to achieve is having EasyLanguage plot a line 20 ticks above a specified price. To illustrate, when the price is at 400.00, I want to draw a green line at 400.00 + 20 ticks.
This is for SPY.

Could someone please assist me in writing this code in EasyLanguage? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I tried, which does not work:

```
if Close = PriceToCheck then
    PlotPrice = PriceToCheck + 20
else
    PlotPrice = PriceToCheck + 20;  

Plot1(PlotPrice, "Price Line", Green);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question, but hopefully this will help.

```
Variables: double PriceToCheck(400);

if Close > PriceToCheck then Plot1(close+20, "Price Line", Green);
```

I spend a lot of time on [this guy's](https://markplex.com/) website. He's the Tradestation guru.